# Relational Algebra: Problems with division operator

Tags: relational-algebra, relational-division

I am writing a query, where I am using the division operator. For some reason I can't get it to work properly, and I can't see why.

```
pol = pi allergen (sigma allergy_type = 'pollen' (allergies)) 
tmp =  (patient_allergies/pol)
tmp
```

The above is my query. In pol I am retrieving all allergens, who has the allergy type pollen. This gives me a 1 column, two rows table, which content is the two allergens who has allergy_type pollen.
tmp:
Patient_allergies is a 2 column, 23 row table. The first column is allergens, second column is ssn for the people with those allergens.
What I am trying to do, is to get everyone in patient_allergies, who has the two allergens I found in pol. I'm pretty sure I need to division operator for this, but it returns an empty list, which is incorrect for what I am trying to do.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I am using this relational algebra calc, provided by our university: dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc/local/uibk/local/0 There is a division operator with another symbol, but yields the same result

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Moreover there are many versions of relational division, even within an algebra. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Please show what parts you are able to do. [ask] [Help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For table languages include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) PS 23 & 10 are not "minimal".